# В какой форме подать текст нейронной сети?

Tags: c#, нейронные-сети

Всё мучаюсь и не могу найти ответа в интернете... Как подать текст нейросети? Пишу на C# с нуля (без дополнительных библиотек).

Просто тест на вход подать нельзя, ведь нейронная сеть обязательно должна получать какие-либо числа на вход, чтобы их перемножать с весами и суммировать.

Я думал, что можно каждый символ текста переобразовывать в ASCII код и подавать в нейронную сеть, но тут вытекают следующие проблемы:

- Количество входных нейронов всегда одинаковое, а количество символов всегда разное.
- Даже если делать такие операции над ASCII кодами символов подаваемого текста, что у нас станет нужное количество чисел, то разный текст на входе иногда сможет давать одинаковый результат, а это не очень хорошо.

И снова вопрос: **В какой форме подавать текст нейросети? Как текст поменять на символы?**

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-ml-dotnet-text-classification-api-preview/

Comment: А что нейросеть должна делать с этим текстом? Анализировать синтаксис? Или пытаться понять семантику?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я думаю, что это не так важно, ведь чтобы я не хотел сделать с текстом, результат на выходе будет зависеть от результатов обучения (обучение с учителем кстати). Ну а если это всё-таки так важно, то я хочу сделать небольшой генератор картинок по запросу (с нуля на C# без дополнительных библиотек): даю нейронной сети текст, а она генерирует картинку. Не стоит мне говорить, что такую нейронную сеть сделать тяжело, я это понимаю, но хочу попробовать.